# GCC infers pass-by-value copy assignment with jsoncpp

Tags: c++, c++11, jsoncpp

```
const Descriptor* descriptor_ptr = msg.GetDescriptor();
const Reflection* reflection_ptr = msg.GetReflection();
const FieldDescriptor* field_ptr = descriptor_ptr->field(i);
Json::Value value;

if (field_ptr->cpp_type() == FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_UINT32)
{
    value[field_ptr->name()] = reflection_ptr->GetUInt32(msg, field_ptr);
}
```

In our case, we tried to build a shared lib with a proto to json function
The linked app would crash with no core dump and we got output in gdb as

```
Inferior 1 (process xxx) exited with code 0177
```

and `_dl_signal_error` frame.

Code line resulted in the error was

```
value[field_ptr->name()] = reflection_ptr->GetUInt32(msg, field_ptr);
```

and we found that `ldd -r` shows the shared lib has undefined symbol pointing to `_ZN4Json5ValueaSES0_`, demangled as `Json::Value::operator=(Json::Value)` by c++filt

It surprised us a lot because there was no pass-by-value copy assignment function in jsoncpp's headers or source code. We tried recompile it with latest release of jsoncpp and the problem remains

However, when we make a stand alone jsoncpp demo, it works fine and `ldd -r` no longer shows the undefined symbol output

We guess it's gcc which interprets and chooses a non-existent copy assignment operator. It may be relevant to copy emision or other optimization, how can we fix it? or how to explicitly use a valid copy assignment operator?

Linux version we use is `Linux version 2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64` `CentOS release 6.9 (Final)`, gcc version is `gcc (GCC) 9.1.0`

compiling options are

```
C_FLAGS          = -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE  -Wno-deprecated -fPIC -g -pipe -D_DEBUG -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpointer-arith -fno-strict-aliasing -std=c++17
```

and link with jsoncpp static lib

Answer (score 2):

The by-value assignment operator has been replaced by by-reference assignment operators starting with version 1.9.0 of the library, see https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/commit/0c1cc6e1a373dc58e2599ec7dd68b2e6b863990a#.

The assignment operators are not defined inline and so a pre-1.9.x version of the library will contain a definition of the by-value version, while a 1.9.x version will not.

It is likely that you are either compiling against the headers of a pre-1.9.x version while trying to link/load a 1.9.x version of the library or the other way around.

According to the readme page on the github major versions (not sure if only `1.x` or `1.9.x` is meant) are supposed to be binary-compatible, but I don't think that this change is a binary-compatible change.

There is a closed issue on the project's github describing the same problem without conclusive answer: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/738

Comment: Thx, it helps a lot. We soonly found there was a by-value assignment version in project base include directory.
So it is likely the incompatibility between header and lib causing the problem